# Need to make transparent textview on gtk

Tags: css, textview, gtk

Need to make transparent textview. Earlier I used gtk version 3.6.4 and made it using CSS file

```
GtkTextView{
    font:Times New Roman, 20;
    background:transparent;
}
```

Now I use gtk version 3.20.6 and make this css, font is changed (so css node is valid) but textview have white background, transparent doesn't work

```
textview{
   font:Times New Roman, 20;
   background:transparent;
}
```

If it's possible to make textview transparent using some code, it will also be good.

Answer (score 4):

From the [documentation for GtkTextView](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTextView.html) (emphasis mine):

> GtkTextView has a main css node with name textview and style class .view, and subnodes for each of the border windows, and **the main text area**, with names border and **text**, respectively. The border nodes each get one of the style classes .left, .right, .top or .bottom.

Setting the `text` node under `textview` is what you need:

```
textview text {
    font:Times New Roman, 20;
    background:transparent;
}
```

Obviously, the `textview` part can be changed to whatever you need, for example `#mytextviewid` or `.mytransparenttextviewclass` so you can apply to a subset of all textviews using the style context.

Comment: Thanks a lot now working, but only if i use two classes in css

Comment: Thanks a lot now working, but only if i use two classes in css textview,textview text{
 background:transparent;
}

label,textview {
 font:Times New Roman, 14;
}